# HTML search by two properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I would like to be able to search for checkboxes which are not disabled (attribute `disable` is not set to `"disabled"`:

My function is below. I am able to find all checkboxes, but I don't know how to search for not-disabled checkboxes:

```
 MarkAllColumns = function () {

if (MarkAll === true) {
  $("#tblArticlesSearch input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
}
else {
  $("#tblArticlesSearch input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
}
```

}

I want to set attribute `checked` to true only on not-disabled checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `:enabled` selector or combine `:not` with `:disabled` selector

```
$("#tblArticlesSearch input[type=checkbox]:enabled")
```

or

```
$("#tblArticlesSearch input[type=checkbox]:not(:disabled)")
```

Comment: It's probably worth adding another line showing the use of the [`:enabled` selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#enableddisabled) (it's really not worth adding another answer to do so).

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
$("#tblArticlesSearch input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', !$('input[type=checkbox]').is(':disabled'));
```

or in your way

```
$("#tblArticlesSearch input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', !MarkAll);
```